# Common method order for Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, model

I'd like to keep my code tidy and follow the best practices amongst rails developers which leads me to this question. Let's say for instance I have the following method types for my model

- Model Associations
- Validations
- Scopes
- Callbacks
- Other Custom Methods

What is the usual order that the above appear in? Please feel free to add any others I might've left out.

**Bonus:** Should you group variables alongside their associated method types or should all variables be grouped at the beginning of the model? Let's say I had a variable to store a regular expression. Is it best to keep it close to the validation(s) or at the top of the model similar to where you would keep globals?

Example:

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, uniqueness: true, length: {within: 5..50}, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
```

Comment: Not sure if it's best practices but what you describe is pretty much what I do.  If you move your email regex until after the validation I think you'll find it won't work.

Comment: Yeah my bad. I meant either close by or at the very top.

Comment: Related reading:
https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#models and
http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/75-keep-code-struture-in-models-consistent

Comment: This is not just opinion based, there are bugs that arise because ordering matters, the problem is that associations define callbacks, just `as accept_nested_attributes` does, and the order of callbacks depends on definition. See [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16823) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what convention you follow as long as you keep it consistent and easier for other developers to understand.

Commonly followed ordering would be

```
1. associations
2. scopes
3. class methods
4. validations
5. callbacks
6. instance methods
```

Some people also move class methods below callbacks. Again, its up to you. But keep it consistent

Comment: Just to mention that this is currently the order in the styling guide (by rubocop) if you want to update your answer.
https://github.com/rubocop/rails-style-guide#macro-style-methods

Answer (score 2):

I follow this order:

1. associations
2. scopes
3. validations
4. callbacks
5. class methods
6. instance methods

Again its really up to you and the important part is to **BE CONSISTENT**.

I put all variables in the beginning, you could put them anywhere but I think it advantageous to keep them together.